# SCP command with a space in the target

Tags: bash, variables, scp, quoting

I would like to make a scp command with a variable for the file destination but, in the variable I have a space.

```
~ $ target=C:/Users/exemple/a folder with space/data
~ $ scp -r -p file.txt $USER@$IP_TARGET:${target}
space/data: No such file or directory
```

How can I do ?

Comment: Have you tried quotes ? `target="C:/Users/exemple/a folder with space/data"`

Comment: Yes I try quotes but it does not work

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1022981/105002

Comment: Already try but does not work with a variable

Comment: Have you tried simple quotes ? `target='C:/Users/exemple/a folder with space/data'`
What are the error messages for each case?

Comment: Yes also but he didn't work and i have "scp:ambiguous target"

Comment: What are the error with the quote and the simple quote?

Comment: Scp: ambiguous target

Comment: the only way it worked is to put the destination directly with simple quotes :
~ $ scp -r -p file.txt '$USER@$IP_TARGET:"C:/Users/exemple/a folder with space/data"'
But I would like use the variable

Comment: Have you tried both of quotes ? `target="'C:/Users/exemple/a folder with space/data'"`
The outside quotes are for local shell and the inside ones are for remote shell

Comment: Yes I try also same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeeded with this :

```
target='"C:/Users/exemple/a folder with space/data"'
```

Or this :

```
target=\"C:/Users/exemple/a folder with space/data\"
```

and use

```
scp -r -p file.txt $USER@$IP_TARGET:"$target"
```